# Multiple select query not executing correctly in SQL

Tags: sql

Multiple select query not executing correctly in SQL.

I have 3 tables, Registration, form1 (Table_1) and form2(Table_2).

Table_1

```
Data1    Email          Data2   Data3

t1     mazhar@gmail.com   t2       t3
```

Table_2

```
Data1     Email         Data2   Data3
f1     mazhar@gmail.com   f2       f3
f3     Raj@gmail.com      f2       f1
```

Table_Reg

```
Name    Email              Location
mazhar  mazhar@gmail.com    Hyderabad
Rahul   Rahul@gmail.com     Pune
Raj     Raj@gmail.com        Lal
```

Table_1 and Table_2 are forms and Table_Reg is basic registration.

I want show counts of value Form not started and form started.

If user submit any of the form data into Table_1 or Table_2 then started
If user not submit any of the form data into Table_1 or Table_2 then started. I am using sql server 2008.

I need Output like below:

```
 formStarted   formnotstarted 
   2               1
```

I wrote query like below but not giving correct result:

```
  select * from Table_Reg where and
  (Email not in(select Email from Table_1 )
  or
 (Email not in(select Email from Table_2)))
```

Comment: any buddy there.

Comment: Poor table design. Store e-mail only once per user. Have id in other tables.

Comment: No requirement is like that only, please update your answer. @jarlh

Comment: Its very big forms not simple. @jarlh

Comment: why down vote, please it will help in future users.

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, the title is a bit misleading. It should better have been "Multiple select query not *written* correctly in SQL" ;-) for `select * from Table_Reg where ...` can obviously not result in the output shown, as `table_reg` doesn't contain columns called `formStarted` and `formnotstarted`. Also, you could have described your problem a little better by explaining the result (e.g. "mazhar and Raj are in the other tables, so they count as `formStarted`; Rahul is not in the tables and counts as `formnotstarted` hence").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count how many of the table_reg users are found in the other tables. This can be done by looking this up for every record and counting then:

```
select 
  count(case when status = 'exists' then 1 end) as started,
  count(case when status <> 'exists' then 1 end) as not_started
from
(
  select
    case 
      when email in (select email from table_1) then 'exists'
      when email in (select email from table_2) then 'exists'
      else 'does not exist'
    end as status
  from table_reg
) looked_up;
```

But probably there can be no emails in table_1 and table_2 that don't exist in table_reg. Then you can do the same by just counting distinct emails:

```
select 
  forms.cnt as started,
  reg.cnt - forms.cnt as not_started
from
(
  select count(*) as cnt
  from table_reg
) reg
cross join
(
  select count(*) as cnt
  from (select email from table_1 union select email from table_2) x
) forms;
```

Comment: Your first query giving error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'. @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: Oh, yes, there was a parenthesis too many. Sorry. I've corrected this.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to achieve simple way.@Thorsten Kettner

Comment: Well, I consider both queries simple. I don't think there is any simpler way.

Comment: Your second query is same as first na. @

Comment: I don't understand that last comment. Do you mean both queries get the same result? They should, as these are simply two different ways to approach the same problem. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: both queries get the same result or not because second one looking simple. @Thorsten Kettner